# Grails Spring Security plugin and dbconsole

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I use grails 2.4.3 and have installed the official grails security plugin

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
```

Before installing the plugin, i was able to access the Database console page in using the url

```
http://localhost:8080/tobu/dbconsole
```

However, after installing the plugin, i am not able to do so. I get the default login screen when i try to access the above mentioned URl and logging in through any user account shows the "access denied" page. How do i resolve this issue?

```
grails.project.groupId = appName 

grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
atom:          'application/atom+xml',
css:           'text/css',
csv:           'text/csv',
form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
js:            'text/javascript',
json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
rss:           'application/rss+xml',
text:          'text/plain',
hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

grails.views.default.codec = "html"

grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

grails {
views {
    gsp {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
        htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
        codecs {
            expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
            scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
            taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
            staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
        }
    }
    // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
    // filteringCodecForContentType.'text/html' = 'html'
}
}


grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

grails.json.legacy.builder = false
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

grails.hibernate.osiv.readonly = false

environments {
development {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
}
production {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
    // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
}
}

log4j.main = {
// Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
//
//appenders {
//    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
//}

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate',
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}


// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'tobu.Actor'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'tobu.ActorRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'tobu.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'/':                              ['permitAll'],
'/dbconsole':                     ['permitAll'],
'/index':                         ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
'/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
 ]
```

Comment: What do your spring security settings look like in your `Config.groovy`? Most importantly how are you securing your URLs? Defaults? What rule did you setup for the URL for dbconsole?

Comment: i am using the ['permitAll'] rule right now @JoshuaMoore

Comment: I think there is 's' missing in plugin "grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to make the following changes to the static rules in the config file.

```
'/dbconsole/**':                  ['ROLE_USER'],
```

Comment: Had the same problem and defined /dbconsole like you originally did. Added the two *s and worked !!!

Answer (score 1):

**2019 UPDATE**

I needed to tweak Shashank's answer a bit for it to work for me. I'm using Grails 3.3.9 and spring-security-core 3.2.3.

I had to add this line to the file grails-app/conf/application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    //.......
    [pattern: '/dbconsole/**',   access: ['ROLE_USER']] 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have the *dbconsole* accessible without my custom authentication made using the Spring Security Core plugin (the *dbconsole* has its own login page and it's enabled for the `dev` environment only). Originally, I was trying the following static rule in the `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` file:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/dbconsole',      access: ['permitAll']],
```

...which didn't have any effect. I have always been redirected to Spring Security Core's login page.

After reading other answers of this question, I have managed to create a working static rule so `http://localhost:8080/dbconsole` is not secured by the Spring Security Core plugin anymore:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/dbconsole/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
```

The trick is to create a static rule for `/dbconsole` and all sub-paths (when *dbconsole* is accessed, it redirects to a login page located at `dbconsole/login.jsp`), that's why the double-stars are needed.